# What are all the legendary items that provide movement speed?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm trying to run faster to improve my experience rate, but first I need to find all the options for improving movement speed other than boots.  What are all the legendary items that provide this bonus?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a cap on movement speed bonus at 25%, so you really can only use boots plus one other item.

Comment: @bwarner there is, but I'm trying to reach it (or rather get 24%) without boots since I have a really nice pair of boots that I don't want to give up.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I found - LLL denotes low level legendary meaning it's below ilevel 60.

Rings:

- [Band of Untold Secrets (LLL)](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/band-of-untold-secrets)
- [The Compass Rose](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-compass-rose)

Bracers:

- [Lacuni Prowlers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/lacuni-prowlers)
- [Slave Bonds (LLL)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/slave-bonds)

Pants:

- [Hammer Jammers (LLL)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/hammer-jammers)
- [Innas Temperance](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-temperance)

Chest Armor:

- [Tyraels Might](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/tyraels-might)

Amulets:

- [Talisman of Aranoch (LLL)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/talisman-of-aranoch)
- [The Flavour of Time (LLL)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-flavor-of-time)

And for completeness boots here:

- [Blackthorne's Spurs](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/blackthornes-spurs)
- [Immortal King's Stride](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/immortal-kings-stride)
- [Natalya's Bloody Footprints](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-bloody-footprints)
- [Zunimassa's Trail](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/zunimassas-trail)
- [The Crudest Boots (LLL)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-crudest-boots)
- [Lut Socks (LLL)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/lut-socks)
- [Cains Sandals (LLL)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/cains-slippers)
- [Boj Anglers (LLL)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/boj-anglers)
- [Lost Boys (LLL)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/lost-boys)
- [Fire Walkers](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/fire-walkers)

Comment: hmm... not many choices that's not LLLs eh that's kind of a bummer

Comment: the main reason I didn't want boots is because my current boots are awesome, but has no movement speed on them :(

Comment: you seem to be missing a bunch, I've seen legendary rings with movement speed

Comment: ah right, I clicked on the jewlery tab on the bnet page and assumed it lists me all jewlery and not just amulets. my mistake - adding the rings.

Comment: Still missing some.  [Wanderlust](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/wanderlust) is another ring that has movement speed.

Comment: and there's [the inquisitor](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-inquisitor), which is a cloak for demon hunters

Answer (score 2):

Are the above answers complete for 1.0.4? This is also a new item that has movement speed.

- [The Three Hundredth Spear](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-three-hundredth-spear)

Comment: interesting point, I was mostly concerned with armor, but you are right, there are now some weapons that boost this as well.